# Why does a 32-byte ASCII text file become 66-byte when converted to Unicode?

Tags: file, unicode, ascii, utf-16, notepad

A 32-character text file created in Windows Notepad and saved in ASCII will have a size of 32 bytes.  When the same 32-character text is saved in Unicode, the size increased to 66 bytes.

Why isn't the size 64 bytes since a 16-bit Unicode character is twice the size of an ASCII character?

Comment: @phuclv: The OP said the original file is ASCII, which implies that it's a sequence of 8-bit bytes with the high-order bit of each byte set to 0. That's enough to tell us that converting it to UTF-16 with a BOM will yield a 66-byte file.

Comment: Some of the commonly used terminology used on Windows is messed up, for historical reasons. "ANSI" is incorrectly used to refer to any of several 8-bit character sets, most commonly [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). "ASCII" is a 7-bit character set, almost always stored in 8-bit bytes. "Unicode" is incorrectly used to refer to one particular encoding of Unicode, namely UTF-16LE with BOM. Outside of Windows, the most common encoding for Unicode is UTF-8 (which doesn't require a BOM).

Comment: @KeithThompson Windows uses BOM for UTF-8 to differentiate them with "ANSI" files. It's not for byte ordering marking purpose as many people always complain

Comment: Notepad supports saving a text file with the system default code page, utf8 or utf16.  The utf16 file will usually be double the size of the first, plus 2 extra bytes for the U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM).  That is how any other app can see that it was encoded in utf16.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode is just a **charset** and doesn't have 16-bit characters because it isn't a set of character mappings that aren't stored anywhere. To represent Unicode there are UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 and many other **encodings** with different code unit sizes. Unicode can't be represented with only 16 bits because it's a 21-bit charset.

Without knowing the content of your original file, if it contains pure ASCII (i.e. only code points below 128) then it's because of the [byte order mark (BOM) U+FEFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). When you chose "Unicode" while saving the file in Notepad, it's actually UTF-16LE and will embed the 2-byte BOM (0xFF 0xFE) at the beginning to indicate the encoding of the file, increasing its size to 66. The names in Notepad are just confusing. In fact the same thing happens if you enter any text below U+FFFF and save as UTF-16. If you save the pure-ASCII file as UTF-8 then the length will now be 35 bytes due to the 3-byte BOM

Mandatory reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)